# Detect changes of CSSStyleDeclaration object in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Is there any way to get notified when a [CSSStyleDeclaration](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#the-cssstyledeclaration-interface) object gets changed just like DOM changes which can be tracked using events like DomAttrModified?

So if there for example was some JS code like

```
document.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style.backgroundImage = "url(myimage.png)";
```

is there any way to get notified about that change in a JS handler without changing the code snippet above at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think, you can keep the cssText in a variable and compare it later.

Comment: @Mr_Green that does not solve the issue, OP is asking if there's an event he can hook on that'll fire when the CSS changes. Just like DOM Mutation event. Interesting question OP.

Comment: @Mr_Green polling a large string is not exactly efficent

Comment: Given that there's no event that fires when an input value is changed from a script, I'm pretty sure there is no event that fires when a stylesheet is changed from a script.

Comment: I just want to mention that it's 2015, we have Object.observe and still nothing works on the damn CSSOM, not even anything experimental. CSS is truly the oblivious smelly kid of the web stack.

Comment: Now that's it's 2018, has this changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything natively available for this.

Depending on your use case, you could easily build a wrapper, so that your code uses the wrapper and notifies the listeners that something changed.

Something quite basic like this:

```
function Wrapper() {
    var listeners = []

    return {
        addListener: function(fn) {
            listeners.push(fn)
        },
        removeListener: function(fn) {
            listeners.splice(listeners.indexOf(fn), 1) // indexOf needs shim in IE<9
        },
        set: function(prop, val) {
            prop = val
            // forEach needs shim in IE<9, or you could use a plain "for" loop
            listeners.forEach(call)

            function call(fn) {
                fn(prop, val)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Which you could use like this:

```
var wrapper = Wrapper()
wrapper.addListener(function(prop, val) {
    // When you'll change a prop, it'll get there and you'll see
    // which property is changed to which value
})

// This sets the property and notifies all the listeners
wrapper.set(document.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style.backgroundImage, "url(myimage.png)")
```

Comment: +1 This is probably the only way that works in all browsers, even in any browser disregarding nightlies.